# How to create invoice / money reciept with html

Tags: html, css, forms, tabular

I am working on an application, for a land developer company. The admin of my application has to make invoices, money receipts or bills.

I need to make them look like http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-invoice-template.html with HTML+CSS.  If you know any sample template links please inform me or give me suggestions on how to design with HTML+CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use and  customize this editable invoice template.

http://css-tricks.com/4865-html-invoice/

here is the [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/)